# My RPi5 USB ports voltage drop significantly below 5V

Tags: usb, voltage, pi-5

I have a USB voltage/current monitoring dongle plugged into my RPi5 USB port. I am running a USB-PD supply. When I plug in a relatively new USB hard drive the USB port voltage drops into the 3V range while the drive is pulling 0.3A. The RPi5 never recognizes the drive. On a NUC computer the drive works fine and the USB voltage stays close to 5V and the current around 0.3A. A vcgencmd has the usb_max_current_enable=1.

Can a RPi5 supply a hard 5V per the USB spec?

Answer (score 1):

If your not using the official 5.1 Volt 5 Amp power supply designed for the Pi5, I would suggest you buy one.

This is one of the very few USB-C Power Delivery supplies that actually provides the 5 Amp output.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/27w-power-supply/

Comment: OP says, "I am running a USB-PD supply." Isn't that the new 27W supply?

Comment: I'll admit I am using a RPi 27W PD compatible clone which says all over its box that it is 5.1V 5A and compatiable with thee Pi 5. I realize that that is not necessarily true.

Comment: I timed out the previous comment. Newbie error...

Comment: I'll admit I am using a RPi 27W PD compatible clone which says all over its box that it is 5.1V 5A and compatible with the Pi 5. I realize that that is not necessarily true. But my power dongle when plugged into the Pi5 and with no USB load reads 4.35V. Plugged into my NUC with no load the dongle reads 5.0V. I am going to have to put a voltmeter on the 40 pin header to see what the Pi5 compatible supply is putting into the board. But that reading will be after the PMIC chip I believe. I did first power the Pi with a 5.1V 5V supply from the 40 pin header pins. Could that have damaged the Pi?